# mktme message after dist upgrade from Kubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 on Dell XPS

Tags: boot, xps

After performing an dist upgrade from Kubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, I am facing some message about mktme during boot-up and shutdown.

Message:

```
kernel: x86/mktme: No known encryption algorithm is supported: 0x0
pci 0000:00:07.0: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
pci 0000:00:07.2: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
```

[image: screenshot]

In dmesg I found:

```
[ 0.101607] kernel: x86/mktme: No known encryption algorithm is supported: 0x0
[ 0.101612] kernel: x86/mktme: disabled by BIOS
```

As I understand this is Intel memory encryption. There is no such option in the BIOS and this has been no issue with 20.04.
Do you have any ideas about how to get rid of this message?

Comment: Same problem here !!

Comment: same here. I heard it doesn't mean anything serious, but I wish it didn't make the boot process so freaking UGLY